# xspace doesn’t handle \,

Tags: spacing, xspace

When using a macro ending with an `\xspace` followed by a small space `\,` `xspace` inserts an extra (normal) space.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\USB}{USB\xspace}

\begin{document}
    \USB-Port (o.\,k.)

    Use \USB to \dots (o.\,k.)

    \USB\,A-Plug (too much space)
\end{document}
```

[image: xspace]

Would it be possible to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\xspaceaddexceptions{\,}`. See section 1.1. of the `xspace` manual.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xspace}
\xspaceaddexceptions{\,}

\newcommand{\USB}{USB\xspace}

\begin{document}
    \USB-Port (o.\,k.)

    Use \USB to \dots (o.\,k.)

    \USB\,A-Plug (o.\,k., too)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But why is this not the default?