# How to keep blanks behind a command without using `{}`

Tags: macros, white-space

How can I program a command `\mycommand` such, that a white space is set printed behind it if a white space is used after it and no white space is printed if no white space is used (e.g. when punctuation is used) *without* using `{}` after the command usage. I understand that this is kind of against how the LaTeX syntax works, but maybe there is a way around it.

With

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][i]{\ensuremath{\frac{#1}{2}}}
\begin{document}
This \mycommand[1] is \mycommand, \mycommand and \mycommand.
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

but I would like to get

[image]

without having to add `{}` behind the third `\mycommand`.

Comment: Since it is a fraction, so in math mode, you should keep it in math; there is no space problem with `$\mycommand$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package is exactly what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][i]{\ensuremath{\frac{#1}{2}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

This \mycommand[1] is \mycommand, \mycommand and \mycommand.

\end{document}
```

See also, however, [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/2674).

Comment: Considering the drawbacks: In your experience: Does it often happen that there is an issue with xspace?

Comment: @Make42: In rare cases, `\xspace` just does not work or it may add an extra space. And `\xspaceaddexceptions` might help. It isn't serious problems, but you may need to know that.

Comment: For future readers: See section 1.1 in http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/xspace.pdf regarding \xspaceaddexceptions and see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76128/xspace-doesn-t-handle

Comment: @Make42 but as egreg commented above, it is better not to use `\ensuremath` then you don't need xspace either (no criticism to Leo Liu who's answered the question as asked:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't see how not using `\ensuremath` is helping with the issue at hand.

Comment: @Make42 see egreg's comment above: the standard markup would be  `...$\mycommand$ and ...` which has no problem with dropped space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah ok. This is what I had used so far. This approach can also be used with `\ensuremath` and a blank after `\ensuremath`. Then one only need to use `$$` when punctuation is followed in the text.